# user type as guest after log in to Site

Tags: force.com-sites

Even if I am logging in to site with custom user profile, its logging in with Guest user. I have enabled login and registration in site settings. Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
/* An apex page controller that exposes the site login functionality */

global with sharing class SiteLoginController {
    global String username {get; set;}
    global String password {get; set;}

global PageReference login() {

  //new start
  //static org-id and portal id
  String strOrgID = '00D28000000HB4x';
  String strPortalID = '060280000004cBn';
  String strURL = 'https://rohitp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/StartPage';
  //start url of the page
  String startUrl = strUrl + '?orgId=' + strOrgID + '&portalId=' + strPortalID;

    startUrl += '&un=' + username;
    startUrl += '&pw='+ password;

    //set reference and attempt login
    PageReference portalPage = new PageReference(startUrl);
    portalPage.setRedirect(true);
    PageReference p = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

    //if p==null, no login
    if (p == null) {
          return Site.login(username, password, null);
    } else {
          return portalPage;
    }
    //new start end
}

global SiteLoginController () {}
}
```

below is the vf component for login

```
<apex:component controller="SiteLoginController" id="loginComponent">
  <apex:form id="loginForm" forceSSL="true">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
      <apex:pageMessages id="error"/>
      <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.username}" for="username"/>
        <apex:inputText id="username" value="{!username}"/>
        <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.password}" for="password"/>
        <apex:inputSecret id="password" value="{!password}"/>
        <apex:outputText value=""/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!login}" value="{!$Label.site.login_button}" id="loginButton"/>
        <apex:outputText value=""/>
        <apex:outputText value=""/>
        <apex:outputText value=""/>
        <apex:panelGroup id="theLinks">
          <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.ForgotPassword}"> {!$Label.site.forgot_your_password_q}</apex:outputLink>
          <apex:outputText value=" | " rendered="{!$Site.RegistrationEnabled}" />
          <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.SiteRegister}" rendered="{!$Site.RegistrationEnabled}">{!$Label.site.new_user_q}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:panelGroup>
      </apex:panelGrid> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: can you show your "Login Settings" ?

Comment: @PepeFloyd, I have added one snapshot which shows the login settings.Please check

Comment: Have you  enabled login in the support portal? If so, can you show the code of the login page (VF and controller) ?

Comment: Also in Portal Settings (Customize -> Customer Portal -> Settings) for your site, if you go to "Self-registration Settings", which profile is setup as  "Default New User Profile"?

Comment: @PepeFloyd, yes login is enabled in portal. I have shared vf and controller code.please check.

Comment: @AshishShukla, I have set 'Customer Portal Manager Custom' as "Default New User Profile"

Comment: Do you see anything in the login history?

Comment: Also, are you able to login using the out of the box (not modified) login page and controller?